# Query only completed orders

Tags: orders, sql, order-status, query

I got following query

```
SELECT  
            CONCAT(address.firstname,' ',
            address.lastname) AS Name,
            address.email AS Email,
            items.created_at AS Date,
            items.name AS Description,
            items.store_id AS Logon,
            items.name AS Category,
            items.store_id AS FeedbackDate,              
            items.sku AS ProductSearchcode,
            items.order_id AS Orderref  

   FROM sales_flat_order AS orders
      JOIN sales_flat_order_item AS items 
      ON items.order_id = orders.entity_id 
      LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_address AS address
      ON orders.entity_id = address.parent_id

  WHERE    
  items .created_at BETWEEN  '2014-04-15 00:00:00' AND '2014-07-30 00:00:00'
```

This work fine for me, but I  want to output only completed orders not created(items .created_at).

How to achieve this ?

Thx

Comment: How can I return the total ($) of sales by month?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/155932)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add `AND orders.status = 'complete'`

Here is the full query:

```
SELECT  
            CONCAT(address.firstname,' ',
            address.lastname) AS Name,
            address.email AS Email,
            items.created_at AS Date,
            items.name AS Description,
            items.store_id AS Logon,
            items.name AS Category,
            items.store_id AS FeedbackDate,              
            items.sku AS ProductSearchcode,
            items.order_id AS Orderref  

   FROM sales_flat_order AS orders
      JOIN sales_flat_order_item AS items 
      ON items.order_id = orders.entity_id 
      LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_address AS address
      ON orders.entity_id = address.parent_id

  WHERE    
  items .created_at BETWEEN  '2014-04-15 00:00:00' AND '2014-07-30 00:00:00'
  AND orders.status = 'complete'
```

Also you can add `AND orders.status in ('processing', 'complete')` depending upon your requirement.